# C macro that counts bits in odd positions for any data type

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I need to write a macro that would count bits in odd positions (in ANSI C). For example, in `1010` the count of such bits is 2 while in `0101` the count is 0.

This is the macro I came up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define BIT_IN_BYTE 8

#define size(x,t) {  \
    int i, sum = 0; \
    for(i = 0; x; x >>= 1) { \
        if( (x & 1) && (i % 2) != 0) { \
            sum++; \
        } \
        i++; \
    } \
    t = sum; \
} \

int main() {
    int b = 44444, result;
    size(b, result);
    printf("count = %d\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

I have 2 questions really: whether I could've written the macro in a way that it wouldn't need two arguments in its signature and more importantly if there's a relatively simple way to extend the macro onto `float` and `double` types.

Comment: If the code works as intended but could just be improved, it's much more suited for Code Review. This site is mainly for broken code.

Comment: Why do you want to do this is a macro instead of a function? What you've got is sufficiently complicated that it seems like there's no advantage to the macro, but you've got all of the drawbacks of doing it that way.

Comment: @Brick it is required to write the code as a macro in the assignment. I guess the advantage of the macro is that you don't need a function for each data type.

Comment: I don't see the relevance with `float` and `double` types. Would the bit positions include the fractional side of the "point"? Or just test the mantissa part?

Comment: This is a contrived example, but ok then.  The only advantage that I see of the macro here is that it is not typed.  Usually we'd consider that a disadvantage, but it potentially allows you to handle the `float` and `double` cases that you mentioned with one macro.

Comment: @Yos: If you learned modern C, and not an 18 years outdated variant, you could use use `inline` functions are be type-safe. Never use a macro if a function will do, too. And with the now 6 year old standard C, you could define a type-safe wrapper-macro with `_Generic`. Your teacher should move on and burry the 1990ies. And your code relies on implementation-defined behaviour when shifting a signed integer.

Comment: I see you have `#define BIT_IN_BYTE 8` but this is duplicating the macro in limits.h `#define CHAR_BIT 8`.

Comment: Don't forget you're destroying the initial value that you're counting odd bits from.  b will be zero after using your macro (or you'll possibly stay in an infinite loop if it was negative)

Comment: You can't do bit shifting on `float` or `double` values.  You'd have to go to some lengths (a union perhaps) to get at the bitwise representation of `float` or `double`.  You'd need to be able to process more bits than fit in `int` on most machines (`double` usually uses 64-bits, and few machines use 64-bit types for `int`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in the comments to your question, using a macro here *really is not good practice.*  You should really use a function instead - inline or otherwise.

Since you're apparently forced to use a macro in your case for reasons outside of your control, here are some relevant points to your example:

- You can use `sizeof` to get the number of bytes in *whatever type* you pass in your `x` parameter.  This will potentially allow you to generalize the macros to different types (you mention `float` and `double`) that have different sizes.
- Since the macro does not do type checking, if you have something that works for `int` in a generic way - probably using bit-wise operations - you'll have a fighting chance of making it work for other types.  I again note, however, that *the lack of type safety is a reason to avoid macros in many cases.*
- As noted in a comment on your question, your current approach destroys the value in whatever you pass as parameter `x`.  That's likely undesired and unnecessary.
- You would only be able to avoid passing the second parameter if you can rewrite this such that is evaluates to a number.  I'm not motivated to figure out exactly how to do that for this contrived example or if it is actually possible.